# Why "/lib/libc.so.1" is mounted on solaris 10?

Tags: linker, solaris, mount

Why the `/lib/libc.so.1` (`linker`/`loader`) is always mounted on `Solaris 10` ? I have tried both `mount` and `df` output. It shows me `/lib/libc.so.1` entry.

Comment: You accepted an answer which, while stating correct facts, doesn't directly address IMHO your "why libc is mounted" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For both SPARC and x86 architectures, Solaris provides optimized C standard libraries. At boot time, the best suited for your machine, i.e. the one taking advantage of CPU specific instructions and features, is [lofs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19963-01/html/821-1475/lofs-7fs.html) mounted on top of the standard one.

Since Solaris 10, no static libc is provided so this dynamic libc, being the interface between the kernel and the userland, is a mandatory component of every program running on Solaris.

More details [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/darren/entry/whats_this_lofs_mount_onto).

One might ask why is this done with a lofs mount and not by a lightweight feature like a symlink.

The reason is a symlink is persistent, i.e. survives a reboot. Using a symlink might then render a system unusable should the hardware capabilities evolve or should should for some other reason the wrong library would have been linked to. Again, all Solaris commands are dynamically linked to `libc.so`. There has not been a `libc.a` since a long time.

Using a lofs mount ensure the first stage of system boot are done with using the safe default `libc.so`, and the optimized one is only selected at the right time and in particular allows a safe boot with all services disabled (`-m milestone=none`) not to be affected by a capabilities change.

Comment: The linked article explains that /lib/libc.so.1 is dynamic, how the system chooses which one to use and what does the mounting. But, neither it nor this answer explain why **"mount"** is used as opposed to using a symlink or some other way of making it available dynamically. My guess is that using mount provides something that a symlink doesn't. I have no idea what that would be, maybe there are some things that need libc.so.1 but won't use a symlink for some reason.

Comment: @benrifkah Interesting point. Answer updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

libc.so is required to run unix commands like ssh or awk that were written in C and use dynamic (runtime) linking.  libc.so is a link to libc.so.1 which is the "base" version of the C library for the implementation of Solaris 10 you are running.

Solaris does not work exactly the way Linux does with versions of libc because there are different versions of sparc architecure.  The lowest common denominator is sparc 1. I have a Ultrasparc III box and other more modern boxes.

Try the file command on libc.so.1:  `file /lib/libc.so.1`   In order for the utilities and other code to get the max from the box, the architecture "sparc setting" of libc matches the box.   Read about and try the `isalist` and `isainfo` commands.